# showDocument() with non-standard (Chinese) characters

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

So, I finally discovered that JavaFX lets you use HostServices.showDocument(uri) to open a browser to the given url. I have run into a problem though; I cannot open up urls that contain Chinese characters. It can only interpret them as '?', taking you to the wrong url. AWT's Display.browse(uri) handles characters without a problem, so I know that it can be communicated to the browser technically. I'm not sure if there is anything I can do on my end or not though.

My question is: Is there any way to make JavaFX's HostServices.showDocument() correctly read in Chinese characters?

EDIT:
Sample string
http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%96%87

You can follow the link through to see the address' chinese character (at the very end of the url). So in doing this, I noticed that it converts the character to a series of %, letters, and numbers. Plugging those into showDocument() in place of the character works fine. So then, I guess the question is now "How do I convert a character to this format?

Comment: I advise logging a bug against the [JavaFX runtime project](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) which includes a sample uri and a description of your runtime environment.  You could also edit your question to include your uri so that somebody could try to replicate your issue.

Comment: This is also an issue with some brazilian portuguese characters.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out that converting the string into a URI, then using the .toASCIIString() method gave me what I needed. (Converting Chinese characters, and I would assume others, into something readable by showDocument(). Thanks for the help jewelsea.

If there is a better way to do this, feel free to give me another answer.